# User has no customer

Tags: python, html, django, authentication, multiple-users

In a Django project, i have two apps; ecommerce and users. Ecommerce app has situation where logged in users are expected to be customers and they can add to cart. Non logged in users can as well add to cart. In the users app, new users are to register, logged in and be redirected to the store page(store.html).

The new registered users does not have this customer instance I guess, reason I'm getting the `User has no customer` `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist`.

How can I integrate this new registered users to have this customer instance so they can be redirected to the store page? or give a condition where not all users must have a customer instance.

(ecommerce app)

models.py:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing a model object"""
        return self.name



    

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing a model object"""
        return self.name

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url


    

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing a model object"""
        return str(self.id)

    @property
    def shipping(self):
        shipping = False
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        for i in orderitems:
            if i.product.digital == False:
                shipping = True
        return shipping


    @property
    def get_cart_total(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.get_total for item in orderitems])
        return total

    @property
    def get_cart_items(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.quantity for item in orderitems])
        return total


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def get_total(self):
        total = self.product.price * self.quantity
        return total

    


class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing a model object"""
        return self.address
```

utils.py

(it is being imported to views.py and then rendered to the store.html template):

```
def cartData(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        cartItems = order.get_cart_items
    else:
        cookieData = cookieCart(request)
        cartItems = cookieData['cartItems']
        order = cookieData['order']
        items = cookieData['items']

    return {'cartItems':cartItems ,'order':order, 'items':items}
```

views.py

```
def store(request):


     data = cartData(request)
     cartItems = data["cartItems"]

     
     products = Product.objects.all()
     #context = {'products': products }
     
     context = { "products": products,'cartItems':cartItems}
     return render(request, 'ecommerce/store.html', context)
```

This the main.html snippet template where both apps(ecommerce app and users app) inherits from.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'store' %}">Ecommerce<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                  {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}

                  <a href="{% url 'logout' %}"class="btn btn-warning">Logout</a> 


                  {% else %}

                  <a href="{% url 'login' %}"class="btn btn-warning">Login</a> 
                  <a href="{% url 'register' %}"class="btn btn-warning">Register</a> 


                  {% endif %}
```

(users app) below:

it has no models.py

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
#from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import UserRegistrationForm

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'{username}, your account has been created! You are able to log in')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form':form})
```

settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'store' #redirecting to store page after a successful login session configuration.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you add the full traceback of your error, please?

Answer (score 0):

Yo must create the *Customer* with the *User* you are trying to access the store.